# Fix "are you sure you want to run this program"?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

So I have this problem that when I download my software (from visual studio 2015) from the internet because I put it on [mega.nz](http://mega.nz) and I click download it will download it. When I try opening it to test the program it asks me: "[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FN7HC.png) Running this app may make you computer at risk".
[image]

This software is **NOT** a virus and requires no admin access or anything in that sort. Some reasons I think this could be happening is because I am using web clients. `<LINK REDACTED>`

Comment: Not sure why this is being voted to close as off topic. Seems on topic to me (with a good answer below).

Answer (score 5):

You can implement [code signing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32012670/net-application-code-signing) which allows Windows to verify the origin of the executable. Then, if you maintain a good reputation with your users, the [SmartScreen Filter will stop complaining](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44839577/windows-10-smartscreen-with-code-signing-exe-file).